# How to avoid unnecessary API calls when checking validity of JWT token in a cookie

Tags: reactjs, api, authentication, cookies, jwt

My setup is as follows. When a user logs in through my react frontend, I make an api call to server-side, where a JWT token gets generated and gets sent back in a HTTP only secure cookie. Any subsequent API calls made from the frontend will have this cookie set, so I just check that server-side before I process requests.

The problem comes in with protecting my routes on the frontend. Right now, I have a higher-order component wrapped around every component I have. This HOC makes an API call to check the validity of the token. The server side basically just returns 200 if the token is valid, in which case the component that's wrapped by the HOC gets rendered. If the token is invalid, a 401 gets returned and I redirect the user to the login page. As you can see, every time I want to render a component I have to make an API call to check the token, which seems very inefficient. Is there a way around this? I don't want to use local storage as I've read that storing JWTs there makes XSS attacks possible.

Maybe I can keep track of the time since I last checked token validity on client-side? That way I can only make that API call to check the token if a certain amount of time has passed instead of doing it every time I want to render a component. I'm not sure how secure that is though.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a middleware that verifies if the current token has expired or when some error occurs. If the response returns an error or expired token, make a new request inside the middleware and update you cookie with the new token.

If you're using axios, you may use [interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) to achieve that.

Comment: My issue is with the API call itself, not with the handling of the response I get from it. Every time I go to a different page within my application (not just the first time), I'm making an API call to check the token validity before rendering that page which is very expensive because I'm hitting the server side with a GET request for every one of these. I didn't know about interceptors, however, so thanks for that!

Comment: Are you using Redis? It's a good idea to reduce database checks.

Comment: I'm not hitting the database in this particular flow. I simply create the cookie initially and send it back to store in the user's browser as http only secure. So this problem is a client-side one. I think I figured it out though. I'm going to use react-idle-timer to detect a user being idle and simply log him off irrespective of the cookie (and clear the cookie in the process obviously). So I'll use the token for just verifying API calls and the timer to take care of protecting routes on the frontend.

Comment: Very nice solution.